# Check which key to hit to boot from USB or CD?

Tags: windows, menu, usb, boot, cd

I need to check which key the user must hit to boot their PC from a USB key or a CD.

Does it depend on the BIOS maker, or on the maker/model of the motherboard?

I was told about the nice, open-source [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) to get some information on the hardware, but is there a library that I could use to get the same info from a (.Net) program and tell users precisely which key to hit on their very own computer?

Thank you.

Comment: Selecting the boot device might need more than just pressing a key. Depending on the BIOS settings, it might not even be possible.

Comment: So there's no way to tell the user which key to choose the boot device based on the brand/model of their PC.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you'll be able to find this out without building a comprehensive library of every single type of motherboard and manufacturer ever made, including any BIOS updates that might change it.

You should just ask the user to follow on-screen instructions when their computer to boots to select the boot device, and maybe offer some likely suggestions ("It will ask you to press a function key...")

Comment: So there's no 80/20 rule to handle most requests :-/

Comment: Every machine I've had it has been different. Old machines you had to change the boot order in the bios, then my first dell machine said F12 to select a boot device. Some BIOS' say press DEL, some say F2, some prompt you after the initial screen has gone.

Answer (score 0):

At the stage you want to press enter or key, .NET will never be available.

Comment: I meant that I'd like to find/write an application (preferable in .Net) that the user would run in Windows and would tell them which key to hit after rebooting.